# Get all id of post i add it by custom query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Now I have this query :

```
$query1 =  "
INSERT INTO wpr9_posts
(post_date
, post_content
, post_title
, post_status
, post_name
, post_type)  
SELECT '2020-08-28 18:30:43'
     , image
     , name
     , 'publish'
     , id
     , 'post' 
  FROM play
 WHERE catid = 863
" ;
$loopids = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query1));
```

This Query insert 114 row, after add it into wpr9_posts table, i need to get all ids added to tis table to add it into wpr9_postmeta table,

```
$query2 =  "INSERT INTO wpr9_postmeta ( `post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value` ) 
SELECT '".$id1."', 'mp3url',`image` FROM `play` WHERE `catid` = '863'" ;
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($query2)
);
```

This query add only one row becase i get only one id by using :

```
$id1 =  $wpdb->insert_id;
```

So, I need to get all ids to insert into wpr9_postmeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple to get inserted ids after query execution such as the @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), IDENT_CURRENT(‘table’), and so on in SQL server.

```
INSERT INTO wpr9_posts (...) VALUES (...)
SET @LASTID = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO wpr9_posts (...) VALUES (...)
SET @LASTID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SET @LASTID = IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.wpr9_posts')
```

As for the Mysql. it is hard to work. You can declare a beginning and end cursors and between them, you can run your query as following

```
    declare start_pk int;
    declare end_pk int;

    set start_pk = last_insert_id(); -- lets say 100
    
    INSERT INTO wpr9_posts
(post_date
, post_content
, post_title
, post_status
, post_name
, post_type)  
SELECT '2020-08-28 18:30:43'
     , image
     , name
     , 'publish'
     , id
     , 'post' 
  FROM play
 WHERE catid = 863

    set end_pk = last_insert_id(); -- lets say 200
    -- result any ids in from 100 to 200 is your inserted id
```

Comment: Of course, it is not related to WordPress. it depends on which database engine you are using. if you are using Linux, most probably it is Mysql